# can we add UI component in TLF

Tags: tlf

We are facing some problem with new TLF framework. We need to add component(any UI component) in selected textflow. But we cant do that.  We need any UI element (just like inlinegraphicElement for images) for UI components. Please reply ASAP.

Answer (score -1):

The framework dose'nt have this future. But you could do it by measuring the text, inserting white space where the ui element should be  and adding the ui element on top.